# I have output from ADC as MISO and MOSI, can I use this signals to TX and RX in arduino uno? if not what will the solution for this?

Tags: microcontroller

I have output from ADC as MISO and MOSI, can I use this signals to TX and  RX  in arduino uno? If not, what will the solution for this?

Comment: No, but you can use the SPI pins that an Arduino ATMega has.

Comment: [Hai is a shark (at least, to German speaking people.)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haie) In English, it has no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

MISO and MOSI are the names of the signals used by the SPI protocol (along with SCK, a clock signal that must be used to synchronize them but which you haven't mentioned), while the Arduino's TX and RX are for a standard (unclocked) serial connection, so are not compatible.

On the Arduino Uno, SPI is usually connected with pins MOSI->11, MISO->12 and SCK->13.  The Arduino library has a class `SPI` that can be used to control the transfers.  See the documentation [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI) for details.

Comment: All of those you mentioned MISO, MOSI, and SCK all available